# elasticsearch search for childs of an object

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nested

I want to search in my indexed data.. that their structure is like objects that contains arrays... and each array has an independent relation with others..

```
{
 "object_array": [
        {
          "created_at": "2017-01-05",
          "is_applied": false,
          "hire_stage_id": null,
          "is_auto_rejected": false,
          "is_rejected": true,
          "folder": {
            "id": 2,
            "employer_id": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "created_at": "2017-11-26",
          "is_applied": false,
          "hire_stage_id": null,
          "is_auto_rejected": false,
          "is_rejected": false,
          "folder": {
            "id": 4,
            "employer_id": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "created_at": "2018-01-29",
          "is_applied": false,
          "hire_stage_id": null,
          "is_auto_rejected": false,
          "is_rejected": false,
          "folder": {
            "id": 4,
            "employer_id": 4
          }
        },
   }
```

for example I search for

```
"folder_id" : 4 AND  "is_rejected": true
```

and the results show this document, that is incorrect!

the point is : because `folder_id` and `is_rejected` are not matched together I don't want this document to be returned..

I know the solution is to use nested query.. but for that I have to define nested mapping.. and that means that I have to drop my index..

is there any other way for this without change my mapping type?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the query that you've written? and sample results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Since your document's nested objects are not separate from the document, it's enough for your query to match the two criteria on different objects.

Your nested object arrays are actually stored as

`object_array.is_rejected: [true,false,false]
object_array.folder.id: [2,4,4]`

further reading: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#object-arrays